# Find full file name using wildcards using glob

Tags: php

I would like to search for the full name of the .jpg image using only the numbers.

I have a folder called "Pictures" and inside all of the pictures are named something like this:

```
100-Lisa_Person1.jpg
150-BillJohnson.jpg
160-BlakeSmith(1).jpg
and so on....
```

THE CODE:

```
$contact_lastname = 150;
$files = glob("C:\Pictures\\" . $contact_lastname . "*.jpg"); // Will find my .jpg


    // Process through each file in the list
    // and output its extension
    if (count($files) > 0)
    foreach ($files as $file)
     {
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        echo "File found: extension ".$info["extension"]."<br>";
     }
     else
      echo "No file name exists called $compartment. Regardless of extension."
```

So this is what I tired but it's saying: `File found: extension jpg` but I need to know the full file name of the image it found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the full name of the file would be

```
$info["basename"]
```

This is because the [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) function returns an array with these indexes:

- `dirname` - the path of the files parent folder.
- `basename` - the full name of the file, including extension.
- `extension` - the extension of the file (this is what you used and is why you only got the extension).
- `filename` - the name of the file without the extension.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11790961)

Comment: @drew010 Could you please clarify? OP asked to know the full name of the image instead of just the extension. That is available in the `basename` index of the array from `pathinfo`.

Comment: It's technically the correct answer, but could be expanded/cleaned up with more detail, otherwise I personally would just post it as a comment for them to try.

Comment: @drew010, okay. I will edit my answer to contain more information about how the `pathinfo` function works.